# How to get the authorized user's organization detail via LinkedIn API

Tags: integration, linkedin-api

The document shows that the `r_fullprofile` member permission is needed to get the user's [organizations field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-08).

I can not find in the document way to get the `r_fullprofile` permission.

I have already created new developer application.

Question:

1. How to get permission to fetch user's organization data via API call.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, I have only seen basic and lite profile member permissions.

Currently LinkedIn provides only 3 type of products, which are given below
[image]

and the scopes are provided based on these products.

For you requirement, you can opt for the **marketing developer program**, which will give the permission `r_organization_admin`
and using this permission, you can use following endpoint to get user's organizations along with roles.

[image]

We also did similar things in our app, where we list down user's organizations and user can select them to share their posts from our app.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Swati.
I have some questions about `r_organization_admin` permission.

My application will allow users to log in via LinkedIn credentials and then need to get that user's current and past organizations list as well as the Years of joining all the organizations.

will this permission `r_organization_admin` endpoint provide me with all these details?

If possible could you provide one sample dummy response of that API endpoint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As per my knowledge, LinkedIn does not provide all the details explicitly, as per their documentation, they only provide the company where they belong currently, not about years and past organizations.